# Passing a dataset to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here I am facing a problem that I want to pass a dataset to a SQL Server stored procedure and I don't have any idea about it and there is no alternate solution (I think so ) to do that, let me tell what I want ...

I have an Excel file to be read , I read it successfully and all data form this excel work book import to a dataset. Now this data needs to be inserted into two different tables and there is too many rows in Excel workbook so it is not good if I run it from code behind that's why I want to pass this dataset to stored procedure and than ........

please suggest me some solution .

Comment: What database? What **version** of that database??

Comment: Thanks to reply Dude but sorry i am using sql 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing what database version you're working with, here are a few hints:

- if you need to read the Excel file regularly, and split it up into two or more tables, maybe you need to use something like [SQL Server Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/integration-services.aspx) for this. With SSIS, you should be able to achieve this quite easily
- you could load the Excel file into a temporary staging table, and then read the data from that staging table inside your stored procedure. This works, but it gets a bit messy when there's a chance that multiple concurrent calls need to be handled
- if you're using SQL Server 2008 and up, you should look at [table-valued parameters](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) - you basically load the Excel file into a .NET DataSet and pass that to the stored proc as a special parameter. Works great, but wasn't available in SQL Server before the 2008 release
- since you're using SQL Server 2005 and table-valued parameters aren't available, you might want to look at Erland Sommarskog's excellent article [Arrays and Lists in SQL SErver 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) - depending on how big your data set is, one of his approaches might work for you (e.g. passing as XML which you parse/shred inside the stored proc)